# When will STS support Tomcat 8?

Tags: spring-tool-suite, tomcat8

I've just downloaded STS 3.5.1.RELEASE, but it doesn't appear to let me run my application on Tomcat 8. Tomcat 8 is now out of beta (with version 8.0.9), se when should I expect STS to support Tomcat 8?

Thanks

/Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tomcat support is part of the underlying Eclipse distribution that is included in STS. The upcoming version STS 3.6.0 will be based on the Eclipse Luna release, which has support for Tomcat 8. If you don't want to wait, feel free to give 3.6.0.M1 a try.

Comment: And the STS 3.6.0 release is scheduled to arrive next week or the week after.

Comment: I'm using 3.6.0.RELEASE, but I'm still not seeing Tomcat8 in the New Server list. Should I re-install STS 3.6.0? 
Version: 3.6.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201407092303
Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)

Comment: The Tomcat8 support is part of Eclipse Luna 4.4. Therefore you either need to download and use a fresh STS on Eclipse 4.4 distribution or install the STS components into an existing Eclipse 4.4 installation. I am not sure if there is a good and save way to get those new WTP components into an older Eclipse base version.

Comment: got it by fresh installing STS 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade current 3.5.1 version of STS just by downloading the current version of WTP (3.6) from [WTP][1]http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/ and overwriting the plugins directory of STS installation. 3.6.0.M1 is released but still contains some bugs in other areas.

Or you can wait for 3.6.0.RELEASE as Martin already answered.

Comment: Just remember to install a fresh STS 3.6.0 for Eclipse 4.4 instead of updating an existing Eclipse 4.3-based installation to STS 3.6.0.